# Parsing occupant's real JID in groupchats (MUC) in XMPP

Tags: javascript, node.js, xmpp

So I'm using node-xmpp-client for a Jabber bot I have running. What I want to do is get the actual JID for the user in a group chat, not the alias. So using code something like this:

```
client.on('stanza', function(stanza) {
    if (stanza.is('message') && (stanza.attrs.type == 'grouchat')) {
        console.log(stanza.attrs.from)
    }
})
```

Will output something like `groupchat@im.server.com/group_alias` and what I need is not their alias but the actual JID of the user. The stanza provided does not seem to have that information.

So someone might have an alias of `Johnny Smith` but their actual JID is `john_smith@im.server.com` so the alias is kind of useless for me with this project.

Any insights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a non-anonymous (or semi-anonymous) MUC to get the real JID of a occupant. See [XEP-0045 § 7.2.4](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#enter-nonanon)

Comment: Thanks, I ended up finding the JID in the presence stanzas, which is good enough!